# block some part of web page to be indexed

Tags: nutch

I crawled a web site. there are a lot of common contents on the pages, like drop-down menu, navigation. How to prevent these contents from being indexed?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, if you still need to do this, but just in case you do, you could try blacklist_whitelist plug-in which can be found at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-585.

The plug-in allows you to have a list of the elements you want to either block or allow but not both.
for example:

```
<property>
  <name>parser.html.blacklist</name>
  <value>noscript,div,#footer</value>
  <description>
   A comma-delimited list of css like tags to identify the elements which should
   NOT be parsed. Use this to tell the HTML parser to ignore the given elements, e.g. site navigation.
   It is allowed to only specify the element type (required), and optional its class name ('.')
   or ID ('#'). More complex expressions will not be parsed.
   Valid examples: div.header,span,p#test,div#main,ul,div.footercol
   Invalid expressions: div#head#part1,#footer,.inner#post
   Note that the elements and their children will be silently ignored by the parser,
   so verify the indexed content with Luke to confirm results.
   Use either 'parser.html.blacklist' or 'parser.html.whitelist', but not both of them at once. If so,
   only the whitelist is used.
  </description>
</property>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am working with nutch codebase since past 2 years and as far i have seen, this aint possible. Once the content enters the nutch segments, you cant strip off parts like drop-down menu, navigation etc from it and keep only the required stuff.

If you or anyone else knows how to do it (off course..without modifying the code), please share the same.